# Why can't I install application in software-center?

Tags: software-center, steam

The main problem is that I can't install Steam basically, but I tried with other applications too and none of those applications will install.

I run software center via terminal and this is the log that i get when i try to install steam.

I click on steam and then I click on buy, it redirects me to login and I login, so authentication pass and I'm logged in but I still get an error to buy application again and this time it won't redirect me to login, it just won't install.

Here's log file

```
2013-06-07 22:19:58,630 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py', 410, '_introspect_error_handler')'
2013-06-07 22:19:58,630 - dbus.proxies - ERROR - Introspect error on :1.11:/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.54" (uid=1000 pid=2318 comm="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/software-center ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable" member="Introspect" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.11" (uid=0 pid=574 comm="NetworkManager ")
2013-06-07 22:19:58,630 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/netstatus.py', 122, '__init_network_state')'
2013-06-07 22:19:58,630 - root - WARNING - failed to init network state watcher 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.54" (uid=1000 pid=2318 comm="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/software-center ") interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="state" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.11" (uid=0 pid=574 comm="NetworkManager ")'
2013-06-07 22:19:58,759 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/netstatus.py', 151, 'test_ping')'
2013-06-07 22:19:58,759 - root - INFO - Attempting one time ping of archive.ubuntu.com to test if internet connectivity exists.
2013-06-07 22:19:58,781 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-06-07 22:19:58,784 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-06-07 22:19:58,880 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/netstatus.py', 168, 'test_ping')'
2013-06-07 22:19:58,880 - root - INFO - ping output: 'Internet connection available!
PING archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.201) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from urayuli.canonical.com (91.189.92.201): icmp_req=1 ttl=49 time=55.6 ms

--- archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 55.611/55.611/55.611/0.000 ms
'
2013-06-07 22:19:59,032 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-06-07 22:19:59,188 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
2013-06-07 22:19:59,197 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2013-06-07 22:20:06,863 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - reopen() database
2013-06-07 22:20:06,863 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-06-07 22:20:07,160 - softwarecenter.db.update - INFO - skipping region restricted app: 'Bulleti d'esquerra de Calonge i Sant Antoni ' (not whitelisted)
2013-06-07 22:20:07,493 - softwarecenter.db.update - INFO - skipping region restricted app: 'Comentarios Web' (not whitelisted)
2013-06-07 22:20:10,229 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - software-center-agent finished with status 0
2013-06-07 22:20:10,229 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - reopen() database
2013-06-07 22:20:10,229 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-06-07 22:20:17,910 - softwarecenter.backend - INFO - add_repo_add_key_and_install_app() 'private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/steam/ubuntu precise main' '33E0E91BDD8E7F4B53837F09E131728675254D99' 'steam-launcher'
2013-06-07 22:20:17,917 - softwarecenter.backend - ERROR - authenticate_for_purchase failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/installbackend_impl/aptd.py", line 562, in add_repo_add_key_and_install_app
    yield self.authenticate_for_purchase()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 473, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type, result.value, result.traceback)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/installbackend_impl/aptd.py", line 502, in authenticate_for_purchase
    yield policykit1.check_authorization_by_name(name, action, flags=flags)
AuthorizationFailed: org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.54'}): org.debian.apt.install-purchased-packages
```

From the last line I see authorization failed but I don't know if this is authorisation to Ubuntu but i have already logged in.

The second time when I tried to install the application I started software-center via terminal and went to *file > install previous purchases*, and there was steam. When I clicked I had *install* button instead of *buy* but still wasn't able to install it.

The same thing happens when I try to install filezilla or any other app.

I even reinstalled complete OS and again having same problem. Now i don't even have terminal to start it from there.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have not authenticated to the Ubuntu SSO or you have an account problem. I would suggest opening a help desk ticket with pay-support@canonical.com

Comment: I should mention that this is ubuntu installed on vps.I have reinstalled my os, and tried again, strange thing is that terminal output successful authentication when i try to login but when i try to download app it gets authorization failed. Ill send email to support and see what will they say.